# Can we grant same permission to multiple groups via MS workflow

Tags: sharepoint-online, item-level-permissions, microsoft-flow

I want to grant multiple groups read access via MS workflow. Below is the URL which I am using to grant an access. Currently, this API URL is granting permission to one group only and I have 5 more groups, instead of making 5 more API hits, I was wondering if there is any way to do it in one shot?

URL: _api/lists/getByTitle('Test')/items(ID)/roleAssignments/addroleassignment(principalId=84, roledefId=1073741827)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know, we can only grant permission to one user/group using one API URL in MS Flow.

We can only put the repeated actions in one flow.

[image]

Reference:
[Set custom permissions on a list by using the REST interface.](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/sp-add-ins/set-custom-permissions-on-a-list-by-using-the-rest-interface)

Comment: Yea, this is what I have implemented.